# Ionic v1 placing icon in or next to input field

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 app that I'm working on updating.

One of the new requirements is that I add an 'x' on the right side of an input field.

I've tried a number of things and this is the closest I think I've gotten to the right implementation, but still doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" style="border-top:none; border-left:none; border-right:none; border-bottom:solid gray 3px; background:transparent; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; font-size:1.2em; margin-bottom:20px; color:#acb2b4;" placeholder="{{profileEdit.userName}}" ng-model="profileEdit.theUserName">
  <i class="icon ion-close" style="font-size:14px;" item-right></i>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `list` and `item` classes, along with `item-icon-right` class to achieve what you are looking for. Here is a working sample:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Input X Icon</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Input X Icon On Right</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <form>
      <div class="card list">
        <div class="item item-icon-right">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Goes Here">
          <i class="icon ion-close"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```